# OpenCV python - how do I convert an 8bit greyscale to only the red channel of RGB and save?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have a grey scale image, and I want to convert the image to represent the red channel of an RGB image. How would I do this in Open CV?

Comment: The way StackOverflow works is that you research your question and show your best attempt at solving it, along with any error messages or problems.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the **tour** (https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), "What Are Good Topics" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: What do you want in the green and blue channels of your result?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [`cv2.merge()`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#cv2.merge). Use the grayscale image as the `b` channel and use similar sized empty matrices for `g` and `r`.

You'll find some help [here](https://medium.com/@basit.javed.awan/splitting-and-merging-image-channels-using-opencv-and-python-f3ba3d9ea0ae) on how to go about it.